# How to pass the subscription to other users using Laravel Cashier

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier, laravel-authentication

I’m building a project using Laravel PHP Framework. I’m using Laravel Auth for authentication and Laravel Cashier as an interface for Stripe.

How can I accomplish the following scenario:
A user subscribed to my service. He is allowed to add users working under him using his settings page. I want all that work under him to fall under his subscription.

So for example when the subscription of the main user has expired, I want all the sub users to get an expired subscription alert. When the main user re-subscribes I want all sub users to be able to login.

I don’t want a complete code, I just want to know how to approach this.

All users info is getting stored in “users” table (that is the default table for authentication).

Subscription info is getting stored in “subscriptions” table (that is the default table for Cashier).

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Use teams and associate a subscription with the team, then use middleware to check a team has a valid subscription whenever a team member logs in.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the reply. Do I have to create other database tables? If so, how should I tie it back to the subscription? Keeping in mind that all users(main and sub) login from the same database table (users).

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this, is to give sub users a status. eg. 1 = enabled and 0 = disabled

Then you could use the [stripe webhook](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/billing#handling-stripe-webhooks) for failed payment or subscription expired to set all sub users status to 0. Then use the webhook for successful payment or resubscription to set the sub users status back to 1. Here is a list of stripe webhook events - https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types

Then in your Auth/LoginController.php you could override the credentials method by adding the following:

```
protected function credentials(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only($this->username(), ‘password’);
    return array_add($credentials, ‘status’, ‘1’);
}
```

Hopefully that gives you enough of a start.